# Python Lamdba Syntax/Keyerror

Tags: python, lambda

I am using python lamdba to update SQL table, depending on the input/status retrieved whilst using the application. However I am getting keyerror or syntax error in the python Lambda that I am trying to create.

My first initial code will led to keyerror such as  (V/SCAN_LOG_VOLLEY: {"errorMessage": "'status'", "errorType": "KeyError", line 38, in lambda_handler\n    if event['status']=="Assigned" or event['status']=="New":\n"]} ) in the status fields:

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            if event['status']=="Assigned" or event['status']=="New":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, acknowledgeTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Acknowledged", event['time'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Started":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, pickUpTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Pick Up", event['time'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Arrived":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, completeTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Completed", event['time'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Acknowledged":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, startTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Started", event['time'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Pick Up":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, arrivalTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Arrived", event['time'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Completed":
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, completeTime = %s, remark = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Completed", event['time'], event['caseId'], event['remark']))
                conn.commit()
            elif event['status']=="Cancelled":
                    cur.execute("Update Job SET status = %s, completeTime = %s, remark = %s WHERE caseId = %s", ("Cancelled", event['time'], event['caseId'], event['remark']))
                    conn.commit()
            else:
                response = {
                "Success": 0
                }
                return response
            conn.commit()
        
        response = {
            "Success": 1
        }
        return response
```

While further trail and error will led to syntax error such as (V/SCAN_LOG_VOLLEY: {"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'src/handlers/Job/UpdateJobStatus': invalid syntax (UpdateJobStatus.py, line 38)", "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError", "requestId": "ea39e6d0-7c3a-41c9-844f-b79cfdb5811a", "stackTrace": ["  File "/var/task/src/handlers/Job/UpdateJobStatus.py" Line 38\n            if ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Pending") or ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "New"):\n"]}
):

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        if ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Pending") or ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "New"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Acknowledged', acknowledgeTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Started"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Pick Up', pickUpTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Arrived"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Completed', completeTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif  ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Acknowledged"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Started', startTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif  ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Pick Up"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Arrived', arrivalTime = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif  ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Completed"):
            cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Completed', completeTime = %s, remark = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['remark'], event['caseId']))
            conn.commit()
        elif  ((status == %s, (event['status'])) == "Cancelled"):
                cur.execute("Update Job SET status = 'Cancelled', completeTime = %s, remark = %s WHERE caseId = %s", (event['time'], event['remark'], event['caseId']))
                conn.commit()
        else:
            response = {
            "Success": 0
            }
            return response
        conn.commit()
        
        response = {
            "Success": 1
        }
        return response
```

I henceforth seek guidance on the resolution of the issues. Thanks

Comment: This is clearly incorrect syntax: `status == %s,`, specifically, `%s`. What did you *expect* that to do?

Comment: As for your key error, that is pretty self-explanatory. That key is not in that dictionary.

Comment: %s will be based the input I am throwing in, based on that, I will perform various updates and etc

Comment: I do not know what that means, what does "input I am throwing in mean" precisely? but `%s` is clearly a syntax error.